# fopen() failed to open file when debugging?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

When I wanted to use fopen() to read a file in Debugging, fopen() always return NULL and I can't locate the error after trying:

1. I just run the code, and fopen() works well, getting what I want. (but failed in debugging)
2. I am sured that the file (hello.txt) exists
3. I write a simple code like:

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char str[50]; 
    fp = fopen("F:\\notes\\assign\\bonus\\hello.txt","r"); //this line
    fgets(str, 50, fp);
    printf("%s", str);
    return 0;
}
```

this code doesn't work too. I make a breakpoint at "this line" and watch how the FILE *fp changes.

before:
`fp: 0x00007ff663b31110 {hello.exe!void(* pre_cpp_initializer)()} {_Placeholder=0x00007ff663ac74a4 {hello.exe!pre_cpp_initialization(void)} }`

after:
`fp: 0x000001b7d6c3eb50 {_Placeholder=0x0000000000000000 }`
you can see fopen() returns NULL;

4. I also tried freopen() and fopen_s(), but failed too.

---

For more information:

- I use vscode. my compiler is **"clang"**, my debugger is **Windows VS** so that I have to lauch vscode in Developer Cmd Prompt.

I would appreciate if anyone can help me. This disturbs me for a long time.

Comment: There is not enough information here. Try adding this code and running net helpmsg on the result: `if (fp == NULL) { printf("%d\n", GetLastError()); return; }` `GetLastError()` is declared in `windows.h`; most likely you need to include it.

Comment: What does `dir F:\\notes\\assign\\bonus\\hello.txt` confirm? You positive of the path and filename. Note also that windows will accept the `'/'` path separator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fp = fopen("F:\\notes\\assign\\bonus\\hello.txt","r"); //this line
```

A failure by `fopen()` (and many other standard library functions) will set `errno` to an error code indicating the error cause. You can turn that into a proper error message by adding code like this:

```
if ( fp == NULL )
{
    perror( "Failed to open hello.txt" );
    exit( 1 );
}
```

[`perror()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/perror) will append a description of the error cause to the string you have given as argument, and print that to `stderr`. If you want to log the error message elsewhere, [`strerror()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strerror) will write the error message to a string buffer.

Answer (score -1):

you need to add the workspace path to the launch.json configuration.
for example  the fallowing configuration ${workspaceFolder}/priv-256.pem".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).